# Hibernate: How to fix “identifier of an instance altered from A to B”?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance 
of org.com.Pricing altered from 241 to 242

I am getting this exception. I have an entity called application which is mapped to Application Table. And when a application is persisted simultaneous some default values should be persisted into another table called Pricing.

The project is a dynamic web project and there is a chance to number of users can login. And any user can create an application and when they click on sav the entity should be saved in the DB.

When a single user is doing the sav it is working fine... But when 3-4 users are trying to save simultaneously it is throwing the above exception. Applications are getting created but while persisting the Pricing getting the above exception.

We are using Hibernate 4 with Spring integration and Hibernate template is used for the transactions.
Is there any way to solve the issue.

@Transactional

```
public class ApplicationDao extends BaseDao {

         private Application application = null;
/**
 * Bean Injection Start
 * @param applicationDTO
 * @return
 */
public void setApplication(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}
/**
 * End
 */

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public int persistApplication(ApplicationDTO applicationDTO){

    String appName = null;

    int appId = -1;
    Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from Application app where app.APP_NAME=:APP_NAME and app.OWNER_ID=:OWNER_ID");

    query.setParameter("APP_NAME", applicationDTO.getAPP_NAME());

    List<Application> applicationList = query.list();
    for(Application application : applicationList){
        appName = application.getAPP_NAME();
    }
    if(appName ==null || appName ==""){
        appName = "NO_DATA";
    }
    if(appName.equalsIgnoreCase(applicationDTO.getPP_NAME())){
        System.out.println("app Name Already Exist");
        appId = -1;
    }
    else
    {

    try{
         BeanUtils.copyProperties(application, applicationDTO);
         appId=application.getAPP_ID();
     }catch(ConversionException coversionExc){

         coversionExc.printStackTrace();
     }catch(IllegalAccessException illegalAccessExce){

         illegalAccessExce.printStackTrace();
     }catch(InvocationTargetException invocationTargetExce){

         invocationTargetExce.printStackTrace();
     }
    saveOrUpdate(application);
    appId=application.getAPP_ID();
    System.out.println("app id "+appId);
    }
    return appId;
}
    public class BaseDao extends HibernateDaoSupport {

protected void saveOrUpdate(Object entity) {
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    getHibernateTemplate().flush();
    }

protected HibernateTemplate getTemplate() {
    return getHibernateTemplate();
    }
}




@Entity
 public class Application{


@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
private int APP_ID;

@Column
private String APP_NAME;

public int getAPP_ID() {
    return APP_ID;
}

public void setAPP_ID(int aPP_ID) {
    APP_ID = aPP_ID;
}

public String getAPP_NAME() {
    return APP_NAME;
}

public void setAPP_NAME(String aPP_NAME) {
    APP_NAME = aPP_NAME;
}

}

@Entity
public class Pricing {


@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
private int Pricing_ID;

@Column
private int APP_ID;

@Column
private double PRICE;

public int getAPP_ID() {
    return APP_ID;
}

public void setAPP_ID(int aPP_ID) {
    APP_ID = aPP_ID;
}

public int getPricing_ID() {
    return Pricing_ID;
}

public void setPricing_ID(int pricing_ID) {
    Pricing_ID = pricing_ID;
}

public double getPRICE() {
    return PRICE;
}

public void setPRICE(double pRICE) {
    PRICE = pRICE;
}

}
```

The following is in the Application Context xml file.

```
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mySQLDBConnectionDetails"></property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>org.com.Application</value>
            <value>org.com.Pricing</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

If anything is needed will give that info also... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit and post: classes for Application/Pricing and your code that update an application instance

Comment: Not related to the specific question, but you should consider having the optimistic locking in place, esp, because multiple users can create/edit same Application entity. Here is an example https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html

Answer (score 0):

```
     BeanUtils.copyProperties(application, applicationDTO);
     appId=application.getAPP_ID();
```

here you copy properties from DTO updating id (primary key of your Entity).

You can store key, copy properties and restore.

```
     Long oldId=application.getId();
     BeanUtils.copyProperties(application, applicationDTO);
     application.setId(oldId);
     appId=application.getAPP_ID();
```

Comment: Not sure that's the issue, the error message is about Pricing#id

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing code real code. Somehow primary key column(s) is changed. That's the reason.

Comment: Yes the ID of some "pricing" instance is somehow changed, I agree

Comment: Tried the isolation serializable in transactional annotation... Still getting the exception